# Django concatenate variables in template

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to pass django queryset to hidden div as a cvs to allow copy text within div. So far i'm doing this as shown below:

```
<div class="invisible text-nowrap" id="report" style="white-space: nowrap;" >
{% for item in queryset %}
{{ item.name }},{{ item.priority }}, {{ item.location }} # and so on many times
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

but method shown above is breaking into new line and it looks as below for instance:

```
some_name,priority_3,CR LF
main_building
```

Is there any way to prevent line breaks in line ? I was trying to use '|add' but it is showing error probably beacause of different types of variables in single 'item'. Maybe there is something similar to {{ item.name + item.priority }} or any different solution ? If so please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you to do the concatenation of values of single variables in views.py and save it in a string variable, then pass it to the template.

Comment: Thanks, if i will not find any other way out i will have to do it in views - was trying to use custom templatetags but still same problem